# Method call with no-op proxy

Tags: javascript

I thought javascript proxy can handle method calls, but this simple script fail to do so.

```js
let s = new String("12345")
let p = new Proxy(s, {})
let x = p.startsWith("1") // type error here
```

Gives me, *TypeError: String.prototype.toString requires that 'this' be a String.* I think *startsWith* method were called with this=Proxy. How to properly redirect proxy's target to 'this' ?

Comment: Don't use proxies around native objects.

Comment: …and don't use `String` objects in the first place, use plain primitive string values only. What is your goal?

Comment: My goal is to check consistency of the underlying javascript semantics. It is very strange to see that some objects more "objects" than others.

Comment: What does "*consistency of the underlying javascript semantics*" mean? If you want to evaluate an engine's conformance to javascript semantics, best run the [ECMAScript Test Suite](https://github.com/tc39/test262).

Comment: I feel it's possible to use proxie around any object, just as in other languages.